# Not able to use For Loop with Promises

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

what i need to do is that i have to click some images and with that the text is changing in another element.
I am using For Loop with promises , so i am able to successfully click on images 1 by 1 but the text is not getting displayed .
its displaying the last text 5 times .
please help

```
element.all(by.xpath(".//*[@ng-repeat='num in facesGrid[$index]']")).then(function(faces){



        for(var i=0;i<faces.length;i++)
        {
            element(by.model('currentTestimonialIndex')).getText().then(function(Index){
            console.log(Index);
            });
            faces[i].click();



    }

        });
```

Comment: alecxe answer should work, but if you still want to use for loop, then call a function from your for loop passing in the `i` value to it. Your code inside for loop should be in the function.

Comment: alecxe's answer IS a loop. The each function is what loops through all of the elements found by the locator.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`each()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) instead of a for loop and find the "faces" by [*exact repeater*](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.exactRepeater):

```
element.all(by.exactRepeater("num in facesGrid")).each(function (face) {
    element(by.model('currentTestimonialIndex')).getText().then(function (text) {
        console.log(text);
    });

    face.click();
});
```

Note though that this is still a guess since you haven't provided us the source of a page you are dealing with - what is `currentTestimonialIndex` is a mystery.

Comment: Hi alec, I tried the code but now using it , the click function itself is not workling now.

Comment: <div class="highlight ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" fadeout-time="350" fadeout="selectedTestimonial" ng-model="currentTestimonialIndex">
<div class="vertical">
<h3 class="ng-binding">"I feel like I'm taking a mental multivitamin."</h3>
</div>
<div class="author">
<a class="ng-binding" href="">Jane Gress</a>
</div>
</div>

Comment: This is for the CLICK
<div class="line ng-scope" ng-repeat="line in [0,1]">
<!-- ngRepeat: num in facesGrid[$index] -->
<a class="grid-item face face1 selected" ng-click="changeItem('selectedTestimonial', num)" ng-class="{'selected' : num == selectedTestimonial}" data-order="0" ng-repeat="num in facesGrid[$index]" href=""/>